# Text in div - automated scrolling with jQuery - jsFiddle inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML: [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yKjD/1/)

I want the `<p>` elements and their text to vertically scroll from bottom to top.

How do i do this with jQuery without using any plugin?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, sorry, i confuse these 2 all the time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8yKjD/2/

I wrapped all your p tags within another div to make targeting and moving easier, but that should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Almost perfect, thanks alot. Is it possible that it starts back at the beginning after it has scrolled through entirely?