# automated scrolling text in div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, jsfiddle

i saw a stack question posted already:

[question]: < [Text in div - automated scrolling with jQuery - jsFiddle inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590333/text-in-div-automated-scrolling-with-jquery-jsfiddle-inside) >

My question adding to this is, is it possible to have the text in each paragraph or separated divs highlighted (boldness, background color, etc.) once they are in main view, whilst the p's or div's leaving/entering the slider box are faded?

So like the jsfiddle referenced, you have a div container with say 4,5,6,... div's or p's inside of it and one div or p is visible whilst the div or p above and below it, only half would be visible (faded), whilst the remaining overflow is hidden.

thanks.

Comment: let's say for the purpose of this exercise, that each div or paragraph is of equal height and width. so the container is 110px high, 60px wide, whilst the paragraphs or divs inside it are 50px x 50px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for an effect like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2RRWS/

My code assumes an html structure like:

```
<div id="scrollContainer">
   <p>Some text</p>
   <p>More text</p>
   ...
</div>
```

And some CSS to set the width/height of the containing div as appropriate. Also it assumes some classes for "dimmed" and "highlighted" paragraphs.

There's probably a cleaner way to do this, but this is just what I cobbled together and it seems to work, so...

```
var $container = $("#scrollContainer"),
    $ps = $container.find("p"),
    containerHeight = $container.height(),
    contentHeight = 0,
    scrollTop = 0;

// figure out the height of the content
$ps.each(function() {
    contentHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
});

// add some blank space at the beginning and end of the content so that it can
// scroll in from the bottom
$("<div></div>").css("height", 400).appendTo($container).clone().prependTo($container);

setInterval(function() {
    if (paused)
        return;
    // if we've gone off the end start again
    if (scrollTop > contentHeight + containerHeight)
        scrollTop = 0;
    // scroll up slightly
    $container.scrollTop(scrollTop++);

    $ps.removeClass("highlighted")   // for each paragraph...
       .addClass("dimmed")           // dim it
       .each(function() {            // unless it is in view
           var $this = $(this),
               top = $this.position().top,
               height = $this.height();
           if (top > 0 && top + height < containerHeight)
                    $(this).addClass("highlighted").removeClass("dimmed");
    });
}, 20);

$container.hover(function() {
    paused = true;
}, function() {
    paused = false;
});
```

EDIT: Updated to implement "pause" feature as per comment. http://jsfiddle.net/2RRWS/8/

Comment: that's great, just what i was attempting to create. I just shortened the container height so only one paragraph was highlighted at any given time. My only other question would be is it possible to add a pause/continue toggle function with the cursor?

Comment: OK, I've updated the code shown in the question and given a link to a second demo fiddle. Anytime you have continuous processing via `setInterval()` you can easily pause it by having the function check a flag as per the `if (paused) return;` statement above. Then just set the flag as required. (`setInterval()` continues to call your function while paused, but the function doesn't do anything. I find this less bother than calling `clearInterval()` and having to restart with another call to `setInterval()`.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Very well explained too.