# how to put a div as the scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

hi i have a div and i want to put it as the scrollbar. this is the image of my div

[image: this is what i did]

i used this style "overflow-y: scroll;" but it's not what i'm looking for
this is my html tag

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mouse {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.mouse::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: scroll 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 30px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mouse"></div>
```

what should I do???

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you want? Are you trying to hide the scrollbar but still allow scrolling / customise the scrollbar / something else?

Comment: simple anwser: you cant make a div to be your scrollbar. you might can use JS/jQuery to mimick a scrollbar, but there is no easy HTML/CSS way.

Comment: Are you trying to make a big wide scrollbar that is easy for some users to use?  Is any of this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523090/jquery-slider-width-variable-li-element-widths-how-do  Although this isn't what you want, you might find some of the script code helpful.  You can't do this with HTML and CSS alone.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13539711/3825777

Comment: @Programmer if you tell a new user to correctly format the code in an unfriendly way, you should format it the correct way yourself. You should use a code snippet next time you want to format code for others...

Comment: @tacoshy i know i should have put the code into a stacksnippet, but i didn't do it on purpose, because the OP might have been confused what these (for him eventually cryptical) additional lines are doing in his code.

Comment: no its not what im looking for

Comment: is this possible that div scrolls??\

Comment: i mean instead of the scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

You should change `overflow-y: scroll;` to `overflow-y: auto;`. For example:

```
.mouse {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mouse {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.mouse::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: scroll 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 30px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mouse"></div>
```

Of course you can delete overflow-y from `.mouse`