# Animating text to appear from the bottom up html/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have my text appearing when a user hovers over it in the following manner:

```
.item{

  color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;

}
```

And then in my JQuery over hover I set the color to black:

```
 $(".item").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("color", "black");
}, function () {
    $(this).css("color", "transparent");
});
```

I ask however, if there is some sort of `webkit-animation` or some scrolling feature I am unaware of if I wanted to have **the text when the div is hovered scroll from the bottom of the div into its place in the middle or at whatever location it resides at**

I am looking at past answers and I am finding some very long and complicated answers for this and was hoping for something easy I am overlooking.

Comment: Please look onto: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590333/text-in-div-automated-scrolling-with-jquery-jsfiddle-inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590333/text-in-div-automated-scrolling-with-jquery-jsfiddle-inside)

Comment: Please add HTML code showing what are the different places you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS transition

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/sepjnuyw/1/)

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid skyblue;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.item .content {
  position: relative;
  top: 270px;
  /* 270px top + 30px line height = 300px outer container height */
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.item:hover .content {      
  /* centering text vertically 135px top + 15px (line-height/2) = 150px half the container height */
  top: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"><span class="content">dummy text for test</span>
</div>
```